# Passing a a value when user clicked on link

Tags: jsp, websphere

In my jsp page I have input field and a hyperlink beside the input field. My page 1 JSP looks like this:

```
<input name="item1" type="text"/> <a: href="page2">Search for item</a>
<input name="item2" type="text"/> <a: href="page2">Search for item</a>
```

When the user click on one of the link, it will go to page 2 where the user will be presented with a list of item, each of which is a link also. The page 2 jsp looks like this:

```
<ul>
   <li><a:href="page1">Item 1</a></li>
   <li><a:href="page2">Item 2</a></li>
</ul>
```

When the user click on a link on page 2, let say user click on Item 1, I need to go back to page 1 and put Item 1 in the textbox in page 1 . Which textbox the Item 1 will be put into depend on which link on page 1 the user click. For example, if the user click on the first link in page 1 to go to page2, when the user click the link in page 2, the value of the link that user click will go to the first textbox. How can I accomplish this? I am developing the code in websphere commerce.

Answer (score 0):

How about the onclick='function(variable);' ? Ain't it gonna work?

Comment: i'll try that. What about putting the value of the link clicked on page 2 into the appropriate textbox in page1? For example if I click on a link in page 1 for item1 I would like to put the value of the link clicked on page 2 to be entered on textbox name item1.

Answer (score 0):

**1)** In your `MyJSP1.jsp`, do this:

```
String textID = "";
String item = "";

textID = request.getParameter("textID");
item = request.getParameter("item");
```

**//** Above code is used when you come back from `MyJSP2.jsp`

**//** Now do whatever you want with `textID` and `item` as it has value received from `MyJSP2.jsp`.

**//**  pass `textID` as query parameter and append `item` as text value.

```
<input name="item1" type="text" value=<% put if condition and append value %> /> <a: href="page2?textID=item1">Search for item</a>
<input name="item2" type="text" value=<% put if condition and append value %> /> <a: href="page2?textID=item2">Search for item</a>
```

**2)** in your MyJSP2.jsp, do this:

```
String textValue = "";
textValue = request.getParameter("textID");
```

**//** Now append the `textValue` as Query Parameter

```
<ul>
   <li><a:href="page1?textID=<%= textValue %>&item=item1">Item 1</a></li>
   <li><a:href="page2?textID=<%= textValue %>&item=item2">Item 2</a></li>
</ul>
```

**Note:** You can change the requirements if you want to but the main logic will remain the same.